# How to make it so that the delay depends on the width of the block?

Tags: html, css, less

I have a menu that works with a delay. But this delay also works when scrolling between menu items. That is, the delay should only work when the menu is opened, but after that, the delay for menu items needs to be somehow removed. How can I do that?

Comment: give the open menu a CSS-class like so: `element.classList.add("opened")`, and then apply the `transition` to that class

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd recommend working purely with CSS using the `transition` property.

Ex if you want to transition on all properties that change (color, width, ...):

```
transition: all 200ms;
```

Or if you want to transition only on specific property changes, such as `width`:

```
transition: width 200ms;
```

Start first to accomplish what you want with this simple approach.
If you need a more elaborate case, you'll have JavaScript involved (will be needed to detect the width of an element) and custom, error-prone code will be required as this is not really straightforward (need to wait for the browser to have painted the page so you can measure elements, might encounter cross-browser issues, you'll have partly your styles in CSS and another part in JS which is less ideal from a maintenance perspective, ...)